# I am not able to save video in camera roll

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

My video is stored in firebase storage.
I am getting a download url of that video. I am using the download url to save the video in the camera roll.

But i am getting this error :

> "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-1 "(null)"

Here is my code:

```
@objc func saveVideoToCameralRoll(vidUrl: URL?) {

        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: self.localDir) {
            return
        }
        if let vidUrl = vidUrl {

            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: vidUrl)
            }) { saved, error in
                if saved {
                   print("Video can be saved in camera roll")
                }

                if error != nil {
                    print("Error while saving video. \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
```

I have checked the video URL in my browser and it is correct. Also, I am running this code in the simulator. Is it not possible to save the video in iPhone simulator camera roll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: vidUrl)` expects a local file URL, not a remote web URL. You also need permission to access the Photo library.

You probably need something like this: (an example using an image)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let exampleURL = URL(string: "http://google.com")
        saveImageAtURL(url: exampleURL!)
    }

    private func saveImageAtURL(url: URL) {
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data,
                error == nil,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)else {
                return
            }

            guard PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() == .authorized else {
                return
            }

            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image)
            })
        }

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating an image object in your code? i need to save video not image.

Comment: its a quick example of how to download something and save it to the photo library

Comment: I tried your code. It is not working. The function is returning from the first guard statement

Comment: the URL isn't actually pointing to an image though, try it with your URL and write the video data to a file, pass the file URL into the photos library code